# Uniform convergence of $f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{1+nx^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Can someone please verify my proof?

> Let $f_n(x) = \displaystyle{\frac{nx}{1+nx^2}}$
>
> (a) Find $f(x) = \lim f_n(x)$
>
> (b) Does $f_n \longrightarrow f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$?
>
> (c) Does $f_n \longrightarrow f$ uniformly on $[1, \infty)$?

(a) $f_n(0) = 0 $ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so $f(0)=0$.

Also, if $x \neq 0$,

\begin{eqnarray}
f_n(x) &=& \frac{nx}{1+nx^2} \\
&=& \frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{nx}}
\end{eqnarray}

Using the fact that $$\lim_{n \longrightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{nx} = 0$$

we get $$\lim f_n(x) = \frac{1}{x}$$ for $x \neq 0$.

(b) Since $f$ is discontinuous at $x = 0$, it is clearly not the case that $f_n \longrightarrow f$ on $[0,1]$.

(c) Yes. Pick $n > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$. Then,

\begin{eqnarray}
n &>& \frac{1}{x^2 \epsilon}\\
nx^2 &>& \frac{1}{\epsilon} \\
1 + nx^2 &>& \frac{1}{\epsilon} \\
\frac{1}{1+nx^2} &<& \epsilon \\
\frac{1}{x(1+nx^2)} &<& \epsilon \\
\left|\frac{1}{x(1+nx^2)} \right| &<& \epsilon \\
\left|\frac{nx}{1+nx^2} - \frac{1}{x}\right| &<& \epsilon \\
|f_n(x)-f(x)| &<& \epsilon
\end{eqnarray}

Note that in arriving at some of the inequalities, the fact that $x \geq 1$ has been used.

Comment: Where do YOU see a problem? (It is in fact all OK)

Comment: Looks good. I'm sure you realize that, in part c, the implication $n > \frac{1}{\epsilon} \implies n > \frac{1}{x^2 \epsilon}$ is valid because you are implicitly choosing $x \geq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

c)
$sup|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|=|f_{n}(1)-f(1)|=\frac{1}{n+1}\longrightarrow 0$ as $n\longrightarrow\infty$